# Where do I put objects frozen with Storable to use them as mock input in a unit test in Perl?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, storable

I am writing a unit test where I need to mock a function that is returning a [Class::Std::Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class%3a%3aStd%3a%3aStorable) object. There is no normal way to serialize these using Data::Dumper and such. Instead, I can do it as follows:

```
use Storable;
my $serialized = Storable::freeze($object);
#store to a file, database, or wherever, and retrieve later.
my $clone = Storable::thaw($serialized);
```

So in my unit test, I will need to mock the function to return that stored object, maybe like this:

```
{
  local *foo = sub { return Storable::thaw($serialized) };
  is(call_to_something_that_calls_foo('input'), $result_of_operation_on_object);
}
```

That much is pretty clear. What's causing me pain is how to keep that serialized object. It very much looks like binary, so I can't just put it in the `__DATA__` section like I would with SQL for a temporary in-memory sqlite db or some other data that might get put into objects. I could put it into a file and store that with my test, but is that a good idea?

So where do I put that frozen serialized object?

---

So Google may index this question for the future: This is in fact about [SOAP::WSDL](http://p3rl.org/SOAP%3a%3aWSDL) and [Class::Std::Fast::Storable](http://p3rl.org/Class%3a%3aStd%3a%3aFast%3a%3aStorable).

Comment: @ikegami: Can you explain that further please?

Comment: Ignore my earlier comment.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was seeing some weird stuff, but it seems it's related to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put it in `t/foo.t.data` and use `__FILE__ . '.data'` as the file name.
2. base64-encode the data and place it after `__DATA__`.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could elaborate on your above comment about it being not portable with Storable.

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the `t` directory, together with the test executables.